# How to find complement of a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of interval time as follow

```
list_1 = [[t0, t1], [t2, t3] , [t4, t5]]
```

I want to write a function in Python that return the complement of the set, call list_2, so that list_1 unions with list_2 is a set with range from [0 to t]. Assume that we just consider 1 digit after point with float number

For example,

```
list_1 = [[10.5, 15], [20, 30]]
```

So if my expected union range from 0 to 200, then the list 2 will be

```
list_2 = [[0, 10.4], [15.1, 19.9] , [30.1, 200]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```py
list_1 = [[10.5, 15], [20, 30]]
start_time, end_time, step = 0, 200, 0.1

sub_end_lst, sub_start_lst = zip(*list_1)
sub_start_lst = [start_time] + [t+step for t in sub_start_lst]
sub_end_lst = [t-step for t in sub_end_lst] + [end_time]
list_2 = [[sub_start, sub_end] for sub_start, sub_end in zip(sub_start_lst, sub_end_lst) if sub_start <= sub_end]
# list_2: [[0, 10.4], [15.1, 19.9], [30.1, 200]]
```